# Language detection using Apache Tika in StormCrawler

Tags: apache-tika, stormcrawler

Does the Apache Tika integration for StormCrawler support language detection for a document? Is there a list of variables that Tika produces that I can include in the output of StormCrawler?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no but you can use [the *langid* module instead](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/langid), last time I checked it was faster, had more languages and was more accurate than the one in Tika.

I am not aware of an exhaustive list of values returned by Tika.